# What determines your ability to pickpocket NPCs?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

What factors determine whether you can successfully pickpocket someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the fallout wiki:

> For each item the player character steals or plants in a non-player character's inventory, there is a chance of being detected (presumably based on the player character's Sneak skill, Luck, item weight/value and the non-player character's Perception). If detected, the non-player character will automatically reclaim the item(s) taken and the player character will not be able to pickpocket that non-player character again (at least not straight away - leaving the area and returning 24 hours later should allow the player character to re-attempt this).